# angular bind animation trigger dynamically to a html element

Tags: angular, triggers

I work on an Angular 7 app that makes use of external components. Now I want to bind an existing animation trigger to a html element at runtime.
I tried this by setting an attribute of the html element using Renderer2:

```
this.renderer.setAttribute(this.miniMap.getContainer(), '[@slideInOutLeftTop]', 'sidebarLeftTopState');
```

(this.miniMap.getContainer() returns a HTMLElement).

Unfortunately I get the following error because of the @ character in the attribute:

> DOMException: "String contains an invalid character"

Is there any other solution to bind an animation trigger to a html element dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

implemented a solution using a css class with animation, binding a class dynamically using Rendere2